# python virtualenv How to manage lib***.so with virtualenv

Tags: debian, python, virtualenv

recently I needed to work on a project that needed python3.4 on the Raspberry pi. I Know the easy answer is just to make an SD card with raspbian jessie(deb8) that comes pre bundled with python3.4 but I wanted to to use raspbian buster (deb10) and `virtualenv`.

I Got 3.4 running but then ran into problems with pip packages that relied on `lib***.so.5` files. specifically openCV in this case. running `ldd /home/pi/.virtualenvs/.../cv2` showed the list of dynamic link libs with a good portion of them listed as "not found".

After looking in the `lib` folder I noticed, the libraries were there, they were just named with `***.so.6` not `***.so.5`

After making links with the `ln` command, some of the issues were resolved. Looking at [debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libopenexr-dev) for raspbian buster vs jessie this LIB is using a different build version.

So my question is: what is the proper way to handle these situations in a `virtualenv`? And if compiling from source is the answer, what is the process to compile in a virtual env? My attempts keep compiling against the system python rather than the `virtualenv`.

Comment: those `.5`, `.6` etc are version numbers, and pretending a given library is binary-compatible with a previous version is just a bad idea

Comment: I absolutely agree, That's why I posted the the deb packages link, to drive that point home.  but isn't it also not a great idea to pull in the deb8 libs into deb10? or am I wrong in that assumption? I'm very uncertain of how to handle lib dependency in linux.